# Is there a simpler way to define a style for line and bar graphs and activate them together in pgfplots?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I want to define different styles for line plots and bar graphs in `pgfplots`, that can later be used independently or together, depending on the users choice. I therefore defined two cycle lists for each style, called `*Bar` and `*Line`. To load both at the same time, I then define another style called `*` and "automated" this step already through the `\defineStyle` macro.

Is there are more elegant way, to create the style, because as you see, I am using all the same settings (marks, filling, etc.) for every bar, so is there a neat way to iterate over a list of colors and create all the three styles with a single call to a macro? Something like `\createStyle{color}{blue,orange}` and `\createStyle{mono}{black,gray}` that works with an arbitrary number of colors that creates the `mono` and correspondig `monoBar` and `monoLine` styles? Maybe there is a more `PGF`-like way of doing it, that I am overlooking?

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=7cm,compat=1.15}

\newcommand{\defineStyle}[1]{\pgfplotsset{#1/.style={/pgfplots/bar cycle list/.style={/pgfplots/cycle list name=#1Bar}, cycle list name=#1Line}}}

\pgfplotscreateplotcyclelist{colorLine}{blue,orange}
\pgfplotscreateplotcyclelist{colorBar}{{fill=blue,draw=none,mark=none},{fill=orange,draw=none,mark=none}}
\defineStyle{color}


\pgfplotscreateplotcyclelist{monoLine}{black,gray}
\pgfplotscreateplotcyclelist{monoBar}{{{fill=black,draw=none,mark=none},{fill=gray,draw=none,mark=none}}}
\defineStyle{mono}


\begin{document}
    \pgfplotsset{color}
    
    \begin{frame}<1>[label=pgfplot]
    \frametitle<1>{color}
    \frametitle<2>{mono}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[xmin=0,xmax=11,ymin=0,ymax=9,samples=2,domain=0:10,stack plots=y]
    \addplot {0.1*x};
    \addplot {0.1*x};
    \addplot {0.1*x};
    \addplot {0.1*x};
    \addplot {0.1*x};
    \addplot {0.1*x};
    \addplot {0.1*x};
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \hfill
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[ybar,xmin=-0.5,xmax=2.75,ymin=0,ymax=11,xtick={0,1,...,2},xticklabels={test1,test2,test3},bar width=4pt]
    \addplot coordinates{(0,3) (1,10) (2,9)};
    \addplot coordinates{(0,7) (1,9) (2,7)};
    \addplot coordinates{(0,5) (1,1) (2,4)};
    \addplot coordinates{(0,7) (1,2) (2,3)};
    \addplot coordinates{(0,4) (1,7) (2,7)};
    \addplot coordinates{(0,2) (1,5) (2,6)};
    \addplot coordinates{(0,3) (1,4) (2,8)};
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}

\pgfplotsset{mono}
\againframe<2>{pgfplot}
\end{document}
```